# Play/Pause Button HTML5 Audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to get HTML5 Audio to play/pause in one button. How would I possibly go around doing this? So the play button switches to the pause icon which is font awesome 'fa fa-pause' The code is here:

```
<audio id="myTune">
<source src="http://96.47.236.72:8364/;">
</audio>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview"     onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').play()"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put an id to the `<i>` tag and assign the `fa fa-pause` class when change of state:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview" onclick="aud_play_pause()"><i id="stateicon" class="fa fa-play"></i></a>

<script>
  function aud_play_pause() {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTune");
    if (myAudio.paused) {
      $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-play');
      $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-pause');
      myAudio.play();
    } else {
      $('#stateicon').removeClass('fa fa-pause');
      $('#stateicon').addClass('fa fa-play');
      myAudio.pause();
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I made some changes for multiple players at one page. Check answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Give this a whirl:

```js
function aud_play_pause() {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTune");
  if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
}
```

```html
<audio id="myTune" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/HappyBirthday.mp3"></audio>


<button type="button"  onclick="aud_play_pause()">Play/Pause</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here You have version for multiple instances of player

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="aud_play_pause(this)">
    <i class="control icon-play"></i>
    <audio class="xnine-player" src="/path/to/file#1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="aud_play_pause(this)">
    <i class="control icon-play"></i>
    <audio class="xnine-player" src="/path/to/file#2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    function aud_play_pause(object) {
        var myAudio = object.querySelector(".xnine-player");
        var myIcon = object.querySelector(".control");
        if (myAudio.paused) {
            myIcon.className = "control icon-pause";
            myAudio.play();
        } else {
            myIcon.className = "control icon-play";
            myAudio.pause();
        }
    }
</script>
```

...