# Audio file not playing on android chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

How to play an audio file when a button is clicked in mobile chrome browser? Because it works with desktops and laptops but not for phones.

Here is my code. Audio src with the song and happy birthday button with onclick function to play the song.

```
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('my_audio').play();">Happy Birthday</a>

<audio id="my_audio" src="Happy_Birthday_To_You.mp3"
       loop="loop"></audio>
```

Comment: Did you try `href="#"`

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it didn't work.

Comment: @Ritesh welcome to stackoverflow. You and the answerer both earn reputation when you accept an answer. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer  Hover beside the answer and click the checkbox. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the 'onclick' and add in `javascript:` before the javascript call. Put it all in the href and it should work ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/jvgvk2m3/))

```html
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('my_audio').play();">Happy Birthday</a>

<audio id="my_audio" loop src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/HappyBirthday.mp3">
  
</audio>
```

Comment: by the way, you'd have more control over your sound if you added in play/pause functionality; it's pretty easy. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24498727/1675954