# Multiple Play/Pause Button HTML5 Audio

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple player on my page. And wat to use the code below from
[Play/Pause Button HTML5 Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498603/play-pause-button-html5-audio)

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="aud_play_pause(this)">
    <i class="control icon-play"></i>
    <audio class="xnine-player" src="/path/to/file#1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="aud_play_pause(this)">
    <i class="control icon-play"></i>
    <audio class="xnine-player" src="/path/to/file#2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    function aud_play_pause(object) {
        var myAudio = object.querySelector(".xnine-player");
        var myIcon = object.querySelector(".control");
        if (myAudio.paused) {
            myIcon.className = "control icon-pause";
            myAudio.play();
        } else {
            myIcon.className = "control icon-play";
            myAudio.pause();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Only this code is not working for me. When I click on an icon nothing happens…

Comment: do you get any errors? have you tried including debug `console.log()` to see if you even get to the function?

Comment: On console I have the error: TypeError: myIcon is null

Comment: well investigate what that error means

Comment: Thanks. Solved. The problem was that the input of object.querySelector(".control") was empty.